# Capturar nome de um Estado (uf) e uma imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa noite a todos.

Eu tenho uma imagem do Brasil com seus estados:

[image: mapa Brasil]

Como faço, caso eu clique na imagem do estado de São Paulo, preencher este nome em um campo text.

```
<input type="text" name="uf" id="uf"  value="">
```

Agradeço desde já ajuda.

Comment: Em que formato está essa imagem? é um SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poderes saber onde clicas o melhor é ter um SVG que tem elementos para cada região e o JavaScript pode saber onde o clique ocorreu.

Para caprat isso podes fazer assim, por exemplo:

A estrutura do SVG ([exemplo de SVG copiado daqui](https://github.com/felipeduardo/mapa-brasil-svg)):

```
 <g>
    <a xlink:href="#tocantins">
    ... etc
```

e o jQuery

```
$('svg a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href').slice(1);
    $('input').val(id);
});
```

#### Exemplo online: https://jsfiddle.net/jaxzw33k/1

Comment: funcionou direitinho! Obrigado mesmo, hj durmo tranquila. Grata